# Best methods access to app from __init__.py create_app() using Blueprints and Flask 1.0+

Tags: python, flask

I'm a bit confused by the changes to Flask 1.0.
The docs suggest creating a factory for the application in `__init__.py` where `app=create_app(config_file)` which is called from `run.py`.

Now in prior versions of Flask I had could `from application import app` in say a blueprint controller because app was not returned from `create_app()`. I can't call `create_app()` again, yet I don't have access to `@app.route`, `app.config` etc, etc.

I've tried and had little success pushing the context. Now there are various not-so-nice ways of doing this but what is the "canonical" way?

Comment: This is not something new to Flask 1.0. It's just the standard [application factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept of an [application factory](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/appfactories/) is not new to Flask 1.0. You don't have to use a factory if your app doesn't need one.

If you do use an app factory, then you usually do not register *any* routes directly on the app. You'd create a blueprint instead, register your routes to the blueprint, and in the app factory, attach the blueprint to the app.

Anywhere you need to access the app configuration, you'd use the [`current_app` proxy](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/?highlight=current%20app#flask.current_app).

For example, in the `views.py` module in your application you could create a blueprint just for the views; I included an example use of `current_app` to access configuration:

```
from flask import Blueprint, current_app

bp = BluePrint('main', __name__)

@bp.route(...)
def some_route_name(...):
    # ...
    if current_app.config['SOME_CONFIGURATION_SETTING']:
        # ...
```

and you'd register the blueprint with

```
def create_app(config_filename=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # configuration setup, use the confuration module as a default
    from . import configuration
    app.config.from_object(config)
    app.config.from_envvar("PROJECTNAME_SETTINGS", silent=True)
    if config_filename is not None:
        app.config.from_pyfile(config_filename)

    from . import views
    app.register_blueprint(views.bp)

    # other registrations

    return app
```